# How to stop alarm manager from overriding my request

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Alarm manager is now giving me the following message, probably since I started using API 23.

03-21 13:00:03.828 754-2170/system_process W/AlarmManager: Suspiciously short interval 5000 millis; expanding to 60 seconds

I require a 5000 millis interval per requested specifications.  How do you tell it not to expand it to 60 seconds when I'm telling it 5000 millis in my BroadCastReceiver? i.e

```
private static final long defaultPERIOD = 5000;
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
    context = ctxt;

    scheduleAlarms(ctxt, (long) defaultPERIOD, true);

}

public static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt, Long duration, Boolean bactive) {


    Log.e("FiveSecondReceivr", "scheduleAlarms duraton: "+duration);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) ctxt
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, FiveSecondSchedule.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i, 0);

    mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + duration, duration, pi);


    if (bactive == false) {
        mgr.cancel(pi);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't.  Don't use alarm manager for such short alarms, use a delayed message to a handler.  Of course that won't work if the phone goes idle.  Also, you're using setInexact-  that already can make it unreliable by several minutes, so why would you use that if you really need 5s of latency exactly?

Comment: It worked at a earlier point, at approximately 5 to 6 seconds, very consistently.  The code here hasn't changed only the build process and supporting SDK and SDK tools.  I used setInexact, which might have been wrong, because if it was a few seconds either way didn't matter too much. I don't care that is different when the phone goes idle, the user isn't using the app at that point then.  So does your "You Can't" refer to the latest SDK?

Comment: All you need to do it open AlarmManagerService.java, and search for "Suspiciously short interval" and then comment out the line below the Slog statement. Recompile the api and make AOSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alarm manager is now giving me the following message, probably since I started using API 23.

No, [that has been the behavior since API Level 21 (Android 5.1)](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/03/23/alarmmanager-regression-android-5p1.html).

> How do you tell it not to expand it to 60 seconds when I'm telling it 5000 millis in my BroadCastReceiver?

Don't use the "repeating" family of methods. Use `setExact()` to get control, where you do your work and call `setExact()` again. This allows you to get down to 5000 milliseconds (though no lower, and that rule might change in future versions of Android).

Comment: That explains it. Went from 5.0.  Will try. Thanks M.